# delay a ajax response in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

Hi odd question to ask but am trying to simulate a user issue upon our site.

Is it possible to delay a reponse from an ajax request.

What I am looking to simulate is what happens to our page when no reponse comes back from a valid url.

appreiciate any pointers

Thanks in advance

Comment: Define "no response."  Maybe just point the JavaScript to a completely invalid URL and let it timeout?

Comment: Are you asking how to create an http request time out?

Comment: Define "no response". A non-200 response? A timeout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this in your PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php

```
sleep(60);
```

If you got a timeout set at 30 seconds, the timeout will be called.

Answer (score 0):

If the ajax request goes to the server, why not let the server `sleep()` or equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

You can make it on server side. For example in PHP script called by AJAX you can make `sleep(5)`. I hope that you have familiar function on your server-side language.

Answer (score 0):

You COULD use a sleep() function in your server code to make the request take longer, but if you are trying to test this against a production server, I assume you want to introduce the delay (or nonresponse) on the client side.
I would suggest a network throttler to simulate slow network response times.  I personally use the cross-platform [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) proxy (no affiliation, but I'm a big fan) to handle this, but you can search Google for other alternatives.